# Python - How to loop through a text file of urls and pass all the urls into a redirect handler

Tags: python

I recently scraped a bunch of metadata using Python's BeautifulSoup Library. I saved all of the urls contained in that metadata to a .txt file. However, I need all of the redirect urls instead.  I'm able to do one url at a time with:

```
def get_redirect_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url 
print get_redirect_url("www.foo.com")
print ""
```

I tried to pass the text file into a list and then pass that list as the argument and I get the following error: "TypeError: get_redirect_url() takes exactly 1 argument (11 given)"

```
def get_redirect_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url 
with open ('openCRS_url.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    data = [line.strip() for line in myFile]
print get_redirect_url(*data)
print ""
```

Is there a way that I can pass either the text file or the list representation of the data from that text file as the parameter of a function, loop through the file, and extract all the redirect urls?  Thank you all.

Comment: You are able to scrape things with BeatifulSoup but can't loop through a file?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html is the module you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you're calling `get_redirect_url()` in the wrong way.

`*` is the "splat" operator: It takes a list as input, and expands it into actual positional arguments in the function call.

So, by writing `get_redirect_url(*data)` you are saying `get_redirect_url(url1, url2, url3, ..)`. However your function accepts only one argument: **url**.

To sum up, you have to call `get_redirect_url()` with only one argument at time.

```
def get_redirect_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url 


with open ('openCRS_url.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in myFile]
    redirect_urls = [get_redirect_url(url) for url in urls]
    print redirect_urls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# UNTESTED
def get_lots_of_urls(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        return [get_redirect_url(url.strip()) for url in infile]

for redirect_url in get_lots_of_urls('input_file.txt'):
    print redirct_url
```

Comment: You might want to strip it.